# Momentum transfer to dielectric thin slit array grating

Tags: forces, optics, momentum, diffraction

I know that when light impinges on a planar slit array grating (say, dielectric transmission grating, equidistant slits), the light diffracts and breaks into orders. If the light changes its momentum direction, it means that momentum is transferred to the grating parallel to the grating plane.
However, when you shine light in normal incidence on a slit array, you will have symmetric orders - m=+-1,+-2 etc. all have symmetric angles with respect to the grating normal. It seems, than, that with normal incidence the net in-plane momentum transferred to the grating is zero, since how would the grating know which way to move?

My question is what happens when the incidence of light is not normal, but tilted with some angle - would that transfer net in-plane momentum to the grating? You still have different orders, some of which could be efficient than others, I believe, but would that give you a net momentum parallel to the grating plane?

It seems to me that in order to give a net momentum to the grating, you must break the symmetry between the orders, which is present with normal incidence, but is a tilted angle enough to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes the pattern would look slightly different at different angles of incidence

Comment: Thank PhysicsDave for your answer! I do know that the pattern of the diffracted light  is different depending on the angle of incidence. The orders angle would correspond to the solution of the grating equation, which depends on the angle of incidence.  I was interested in the total momentum transfer to the slit array.

Comment: Yes momentum is applied to the slit but it is very very small compared to whatever the slit is mounted to.  Probably can't be measured it's so small.  But yes momentum is always conserved.